# Can plasma retain a magnetic field? even for the tiniest fraction of a second?

Tags: magnetic-fields, plasma-physics

If I subject plasma to a magnetic field, can it retain that field after the magnetic field suddenly ceases(the magnetic field disappears is a planck second)
for *even the tiniest fraction of a second is the plasma "ferromagnetic"*?

Answer (score 4):

The magnetic field in a conductor (such as a plasma) obeys a version of the [diffusion equation](http://web.mit.edu/6.013_book/www/chapter10/10.5.html):
$$
\frac{1}{\mu_0 \sigma} \nabla^2 \vec{B} = \frac{\partial \vec{B}}{\partial t}
$$
where we have assumed negligible magnetic susceptibility ($\mu \approx \mu_0$) and uniform conductivity $\sigma$.  This means that if we create a magnetic field in some region of a plasma, it will eventually decay away, just like a solute concentrated in a small part of a fluid will eventually spread out and reduce its concentration to practically zero.

This does not happen instantaneously, though;  the time scale on which this occurs is on the order of
$$
\tau \approx \mu_0 \sigma L^2,
$$
where $L$ is the approximate size of the region of magnetic field non-uniformity.  We can see that the larger the conductivity is, or the larger the region of non-uniform magnetic field, the longer the field will last;  but eventually it will decay away.

Finally: while this time scale for demagnetization can be quite long, and so the plasma can behave a little like a ferromagnet in that regard, it is not what I (or most physicists, I think) would refer to as proper ferromagnetism.  In particular, the behavior of a magnetic field in a plasma can be described entirely classically, is largely due to the large-scale motion of charges, and does not change radically when plasma gets too hot.  None of the above statements are true of ferromagnets.

Comment: I know that plasma can trap magnetic fields, the coronal mass ejections carry magnetic fields with them which interact with earths's field etc, so there are conditions where the fields last long enough ( to come from the sun). This was from a dynamo model and plasma discussion for the sun some years ago, and I cannot find a reference. Do you have a reference?

Comment: @annav:  I think you're thinking of [Alfvén's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfv%C3%A9n's_Theorem), which only holds exactly in the limit of infinite conductivity $\sigma$.  However, the time-scale of magnetic diffusion for solar phenomena can be on the order of thousands of years due to the high conductivities and large scales involved, and millions of years for plasmas in the interstellar medium.  (At least, that's what a quick internet search tells me;  I await corrections by anyone who knows better.)

Comment: This is from ejections from the sun.  According to Wiki it takes from one to five days. \\"The wind is a ‘plasma’, it is an overall electrically neutral mixture of positive and negatively charged particles. Plasmas trap magnetic fields and the solar wind carries not only particles to earth but also the sun’s magnetism." http://www.atoptics.co.uk/highsky/auror2.htm  but I have not found a solid description, just words.

Comment: Is there a place I could find a chart that can tell me how long the magnetic fields of various kinds  of plasmas would last under various or similar circumstances?